# React Native TextInput grabbing highlighted text, and keeping it highlighted when I click away

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have two things I want to do.

1. when I select text inside of a TextInput, and click on a button I would like to keep the text highlighted.
2. How can I grab the highlighted text from a TextInput?

Shouldn't there be properties and events that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has answered I will give my solution.

My solution was to create a custom component and make callback to delegates of UITextView

```
-(void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{  

  NSDictionary *event = @{
                          @"target": textView.reactTag,
                          @"highlights": @{
                              @"text": textView.text,
                              @"range": @(textView.selectedRange.length),
                              @"cursorPosition": @(textView.selectedRange.location),
                              @"eventType": @"textViewDidChangeSelection",
                              }
                          };
  [self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendInputEventWithName:@"topChange" body:event];
}
```

Then In my Javascript file

```
setText(event: Event){
        if(event !== undefined){
        if(event.nativeEvent.highlights.eventType == "shouldChangeTextInRange" && event.nativeEvent.highlights.range > 0){
//do stuff
                }
            }   
        },
```